# Can I import Network Dataset in PostgreSQL through pgRouting or Polyline Shapefile?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I need to make an application for the Quickest Route to the nearby hospitals from the incident place. I have read many articles and papers but I am confused whether I need polyline shapefile or network dataset or any other format for storing data in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends of what you need to achieve... but If you need only data for routing to be done in PostgreSQL (so assuming postGIS and PGRouting) you'll need a topology (network).

You can use [OSM2PO](http://osm2po.de/) to convert OSM data into topology and write it as sql script, than import into database using PSQL.

[Here is nice instruction](https://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=pgrouting_osm2po_1) how to do this